# Unserialize non standard string

Tags: php, deserialization

I have a string which looks like an array:-

```
'[["hello","world"],["etc","etc..."]]'
```

Is there a way to 'unserialize' this even though it is not really proper serialized format.

Comment: What is it that is improper/incorrect about the serialized data. What you have posted is a JSON serialized object.

Comment: I meant it's not what an array serialized by php serialize() looks like. php's unserialize() function doesn't work on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return it as an array as it is JSON:

```
$json = '[["hello","world"],["etc","etc..."]]';
$decoded = json_decode($json, true); // true option returns associative array
print_r($decoded);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => world
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => etc
            [1] => etc...
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function on this string.